# Difference betweem reappraise, reassess and reevaluate?

Tags: differences

Could someone please tell me what is the difference between these words, or is there any or I can use them the same way in different kind of contexts?

**reappraise, reassess and reevaluate**

For example, if I want to place it into a context where I talk about my change view what would fit the best?

> T̶h̶e̶ ̶t̶o̶u̶r̶ ̶a̶t̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶z̶o̶o̶ ̶r̶e̶a̶p̶p̶r̶a̶i̶s̶e̶d̶/̶r̶e̶a̶s̶s̶e̶s̶s̶e̶d̶/̶r̶e̶e̶v̶a̶l̶u̶a̶t̶e̶d̶ ̶m̶y̶ ̶v̶i̶e̶w̶ ̶o̶f̶.̶.̶.̶.̶
>
> Answer:
>
> - The tour at the zoo made me reevaluate/reassess my view of

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are different verbs with different denotations and connotations.

to appraise is in fact synonymous with to assess however they invoke a different perceived action. An appraisal of something is usually associated with values, and I feel that an appraising is a very professional sounding term(seeing as it is the root for an occupation that does the action) therefore in casual or personal situations it seems inappropriate. That is especially true since you usually really appraise items or objects mostly not views and concepts.

evaluate and assess do have slight connotation differences depending on context but overall I would say they care the same meaning. However, in you example "reevaluate" would sound better. Also the sentence you gave is actually incorrect. In it you are stating the tour itself reevaluated your view... That is very wrong as tours are concepts and cannot preform actions like evaluate things.

A better sentence would be "The tour at the zoo made me reevaluate my view of"

I really hope this helped you Sir or Madam. You have a wonderful day!

Comment: Welcome, any time!